# Completing survey on Google Forms without a Google account

Tags: google-forms

I have created a survey using Google Forms and need to send to University staff. How can I restrict to only one response per person without survey group having a Google account?

Comment: Related: [How to limit one response per email for Google Forms](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/85240/354)

Comment: In [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92979/) I describe how one can achieve this by sending out a unique token to each recipient. (Some recipients may be concerned about losing anonymity as a result of submitting a form with a token.)

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  With anonymous people filling in the survey there is no way to tell if they have done it more than once.

You could have the users enter an email address into the form and then use Google Apps Script to check.  However, if they enter a different email address you are back to square one.

Comment: This was three years ago. Is it still the case that we cannot limit anonymous respondents (eg random consumers visiting a site) to one response per IP address?